# Please wait message while page with visual webpart is loading

Tags: visual-web-part

I have a page which consists of a Visual webpart. The user goes to the page by clicking on the Sharepoint default side nav. The page I mentioned earlier takes a while to load and I would like to have a "page is loading" message to be displayed while this happens. Is there a way to do it on the page load function of my visual webpart?

Please advice.

Comment: check this one http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/04/sharepoint-create-a-wait-message-for-long-running-tasks/

Comment: I am not accessing the page through button, I am doing it through a link in side nav.